# Google: "302 Moved" in Firefox

Tags: firefox

For some Google search queries executed from the Firefox search bar, or manually by typing in the URL, I get a ''302 Moved'' page. I did a quick virus scan, have checked the `hosts` file and the plugins and add-ons that are installed in Firefox. Nothing is out of the ordinary. What could be the problem?

These URLs (and any URL with `google.com`, `empty` and `firefox-a` in them) show me a 302 Moved page:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+empty+array&client=firefox-a
- https://www.google.com/search?q=empty&client=firefox-a

Whereas these URLs work fine:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+empty+array (no `firefox-a`)
- https://www.google.com/search?q=empty (no `firefox-a`)
- https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+array&client=firefox-a (no `empty`)
- https://www.google.nl/search?q=c%23+empty+array&client=firefox-a (no `.com`)

By default Google redirects my queries to their `.nl` website, and uses HTTPS. I am currently executing a full system virus scan using Security Essentials. My Firefox plugins were up-to-date. No unfamiliar Firefox plugins or add-ons found. Restarting Firefox did not solve the issue. The issue does not occur in Internet Explorer. The `hosts` file did not contain any unfamiliar entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After restarting Firefox with all add-ons and plugins disabled, the issue went away. By enabling each add-on and testing it, I found that [DoNotTrack+](http://www.abine.com/dntdetail.php) is the culprit.

However, I don't know how to solve it. I cannot add `google.com` to the whitelist as there are no trackers to block. And even so, I am not sure that whitelisting Google would solve the problem.

Comment: You should ask a follow-up question about making Google play nice with DoNotTrack+ if it has not already been asked here :) I think you can also mark your own answer as the answer for the question.

Comment: Was having the same issue with either disconnect or ghostery - didn't have the time to isolate which

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at your Firefox>Add-ons>EXTENSIONS

You may find that there is an active add-on called NoRedirect and it is ENABLED.

For me the "302" problem was gone once I disabled this add-on.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens to me; I searched something into the Address Bar, and Google displays their "302 Moved" page.

However, the solution maybe:

1. **Removing the Country Extension**

   a. The Country Extension (i.e., google`.uk`, google`.us`, google`.eu`, ...) should be removed from the address bar, if only you are searching through the Address Bar.

   b. The Address Bar should now look like this: http://www.google.com/search?q=Your+Search+Here
2. **Adding the `gws_rd=ssl` Query String**

   a. If you are searching manually (i.e., typing `http://www.google.com/search?q=Your+Search+Here` into your address bar), try adding the Query String `gws_rd=ssl`.  The URL should now look like this: http://www.google.com/search?q=Your+Search+Here&gws_rd=ssl.  (*Try removing the `&gws_rd=ssl` on the Address Bar, it will show the 302 Moved Page*)

***Hope this works!***